# How can I get original character?

Tags: c#, events, keycode

I want to get a TextBox input key.

I was generate "KeyDown" event and
using the next

```
string inputKey = new KeysConverter().ConvertToString(e.KeyCode)
```

bun it is only assign upper case.

I want both upper case and lower case.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried "e.KeyChar" ?

Comment: There is no KeyChar property for KeyEventArgs. @wazaaaap

Comment: did you mean inputKey.ToLower() ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using KeyDown Event This is what you need.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string inputKey;

        bool capsLock = IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock); // Check for capslock is on
        bool shift = e.Shift; // Check for Shift button was pressed

        if ((shift && !capsLock) || (!shift && capsLock))
        {
            inputKey = new KeysConverter().ConvertToString(e.KeyCode);
        }
        else if ((shift && capsLock) || (!shift && !capsLock))
        {
            inputKey = new KeysConverter().ConvertToString(e.KeyCode).ToLower();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the KeyPress event and then get the character with e.KeyChar.

For example:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString());
}
```